# Can you recommend a lightweight java portlet software?

Tags: java, portlet

I am a long time java web developer but I am new to portlets technology.

Currently I am in the stage of finding my options.

I have tried [Liferay](http://www.liferay.com/products/liferay-portal) and although it is very cool, it is a bit heavy for my needs.

Can you recommend a more lightweight portlet container?

Comment: what are you finding heavyweight about it?

Comment: hmmm... portlets.... lightweight.... curious idea....

Answer (score 4):

I think that the JSR-168/286 reference implementation [Apache Pluto](http://portals.apache.org/pluto/) is probably going to be as lightweight as you are going to get.

Most, if not all, portlet products are targeted firmly at the enterprise market which means they tend to come shipped as part of a 'heavyweight' enterprise portal product, even though the portlet (producer) component should generally be fairly lightweight.

Answer (score 1):

You could have a look at [Jetspeed portal](http://portals.apache.org/jetspeed-2/), part of the [Apache Portals Project](http://portals.apache.org/) . Although I don't really think it classifies as 'lightweight'.

Answer (score 1):

Portals are quite heavyweight by nature, but I've found the [Pluto](http://portals.apache.org/pluto/) portlet container useful for testing individual portlets as it can be set up on Tomcat or Jetty in a few minutes and requires minimal initial configuration. Pluto is used as the portlet container by [Jetspeed](http://portals.apache.org/jetspeed-2/).

Answer (score 0):

Try [Open Portal Portlet Container](http://portlet-container.java.net/) . It is a lightweight portlet container.